# Expected expression before 'unsigned' ->Objective C

Tags: objective-c

m_cAppIdMap is an object of a dictionary.
I want to iterate through the dictionary and to ind and remove the value pEvent.wTimerId is an unsigned short integer that is stored as key in the dictionary.

```
if(unsigned short* key in m_cAppIdMap) //error:Expected expression before 'unsigned'
            {
            (void)[self findAndRemoveEvent:pEvent];
            (void)CFDictionaryRemoveValue(m_cAppIdMap,&wTimerId); 
            free(pEvent);
            bReturn = YES;
           }
```

I am getting an error when i try to iterate through the loop.

EDITED

```
-(BOOL)KillTimer:(unsigned short)wTimerId
{
    stRs232Timer* pEvent;
    BOOL bReturn=FALSE;

    theLock = [[NSLock alloc]init];

    if ([theLock tryLock]) {
    //  if ( m_cAppIdMap.Lookup(wTimerId,pEvent) )
    //  {
    //      (void)findAndRemoveEvent(pEvent);                   // remove from event queue
    //      (void)m_cAppIdMap.RemoveKey(wTimerId);              // remove from app map
            for(wTimerId in m_cAppIdMap)
            {
             (void)[self findAndRemoveEvent:pEvent];
             (void)CFDictionaryRemoveValue(m_cAppIdMap,&wTimerId); 
             free(pEvent);
             bReturn = YES;
           }

        [theLock unlock];
    }   

    return bReturn;
}
```

I am getting error in this code 'selector element does not have a valid object type' . I need to search for `wTimerId(key)` in the m_cAppIdMap. Is it what i'm doing is correct.The commented lines above the for loop is the implementation of the same code in cpp. I coud not make the same logic over here in Objective C.

Comment: @Chris & Justin:Thanks.The error got cleared but still i could not find how to look for the wTimerId(key),pEvent(value) in the dictionary m_cAppIdMap(dictionary containing wTimerIdMap(key) and pEvent(value))

Comment: if i correct with for "for(wTimerId in m_cAppIdMap)" 'I am getting at the end of the loop stating that' "selector element does not have a valid object type"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you meant to use `for` rather than `if`. Additionally, the fast enumeration syntax
`for (x in y)` can only be used on objects that implement the `NSFastEnumeration` protocol—typically `NSArray`. It looks like you're using C arrays, so this syntax won't work anyway.

Answer (score 3):

you meant to write `for (VARIABLE in CONTAINER) {...}` -- but your sample uses `if`, not `for`.

side note: it is an error to mutate the collections you iterate over during the iteration.